# Unclosed character in matching string for splitting operation in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have the following information in a pyspark data frame column:

```
[["A"],["B"]]
```

and

```
["A","B"]
```

I would like to split the column where the values appear as per the first instance, and leave the values in the second instance intact.

However, upon trying to do this via the `split` operation:

```
df = df.selectExpr("split(col, '],[') col")
```

I recieve the following error:

```
'Unclosed character class near index...'
```

I have also tried to replace the actual characters with their ascii equivalent:

```
df = df.selectExpr("split(col, '\x5D\2C\x5B') col")
```

But it resulted in the same error as above.

Any suggestions are welcome. Tnx.

Comment: i don't think the column has values as `'["A"],["B"]'`. My guess is it is an array of arrays (or elements). you could try to use `func.flatten()` to flatten the array of arrays.

Comment: Hi @samkart, would the above splitting operation work if it was an array? As it is the case when I use only ',' as matching string for the splitting.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by your statement? Do you mean splitting using `,` works?

Comment: @samkart the column is a string column, it can have any value, no matter what you think

Comment: so it is saved as `'["A"],["B"]'` and not `["A"],["B"]`. Is that correct?

Comment: @samkart, so if I am splitting for a comma, that is, ',' then it works. But the challenge is to only split the [["A"], ["B"]] and not split where ["A", "B"] appears. Splitting on the comma does not resolve this.

Comment: just throwing an idea -- have you tried escape characters? `df = df.selectExpr("split(col, '\],\[') col")` -- or why not just remove the characters altogether - `func.regexp_replace(\],\[', '')`

Answer (score 0):

there is obviously something very strange when you use the char `[`. If you remove this char, there is no error anymore.

But you can also use the function version of split and it solves the issue :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(F.split(F.col("col"), '],\[')).show()
+----------------+
|split(col, ],\[)|
+----------------+
|  [[["A", "B"]]]|
|     [["A","B"]]|
+----------------+
```

---

If we do not consider your actual problem with split but the real use case you're facing, `from_json` is probably a better idea :

```py
schema_1 = T.ArrayType(T.StringType())
schema_2 = T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

df2 = df.select(
    "col",
    F.from_json("col", schema_1),
    F.from_json("col", schema_2)
)

df2.show()
+-------------+------------------+------------------+                           
|          col|jsontostructs(col)|jsontostructs(col)|
+-------------+------------------+------------------+
|[["A"],["B"]]|    [["A"], ["B"]]|        [[A], [B]]|
|    ["A","B"]|            [A, B]|              null|
+-------------+------------------+------------------+

df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- jsontostructs(col): array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- jsontostructs(col): array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```